# delphi android firemonkey camera launch

Tags: android, delphi, camera, firemonkey

I want to launch the phones native camera application from within my application. So I don't have to recreate a picture taking application. How do I do it.

Using 10.21

thanks
robert

Answer (score 0):

On Android, the tool called [adb](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html?hl=pt-br) (bundled with Android SDK) is the bridge between computer and device. You can run commands from a terminal in order to interact with many features of Android OS.

With Delphi, your application can run the commands directly in **cmd**.

In order to take a picture, you can follow the tutorial [here](https://coderwall.com/p/3-tgjg/take-a-photo-via-adb).

Then just pull the generated file from device, for instance `adb pull /path/to/filename.jpg %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\`.

Answer (score 0):

From a Delphi app you can use a TActionList and it's standard action TakePhotoFromCameraAction.

To use it from a button, add a TActionList to your form, on the button set Action property to TakePhotoFromCameraAction.

With code only:

- add unit FMX.MediaLibrary.Actions
- create a varaible TakePhotoFromCameraAction1 of type TTakePhotoFromCameraAction
- set it's TakePhotoFromCameraAction1.DidFinishTaking event to a method like this :

  procedure TForm1.TakePhotoFromCameraAction1DidFinishTaking(Image: TBitmap);
  begin
    //...
  end;
- call TakePhotoFromCameraAction1.Execute when needed

Comment: thank you. I did find this yesterday. It is simple. I was caught up trying to use the camera component.